# Neo4j Random query throws error

Tags: neo4j

I have been using neo4j on my local machine for a while and it seemed to work well, but suddenly for one specific query I am getting this error message (all other queries are working fine):

WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3

The query I am trying to run is this:

```
match (p:Node1)-[c:Relation]->(q:Node2)
SET c.attribute = false;
```

Every other query is working fine, I can set any attribute I want, just for this query, the console computes for a while, the pc starts lagging and then throws the exception. Maybe it is a timeout issue or something?

I have seen in a couple of posts, that it might have something to do with my Java version? I am using oracle-8 java version:

```
 "1.8.0_161" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Anyone any idea what I could try?

I also tried uncommenting these lines in the conf file, but it did not help.

```
# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

Thank you very much in advance for your ideas and suggestions.

Cheers

Comment: Instead of setting, can you `RETURN count(c)`? Does that work, and how many relationships is it finding?

Comment: Hi, there are quite a lot: 25,166,994 Relations. Do you think that might be the problem? That the console runs into a timeout?

Comment: Yes, that would absolutely do it. I'll add an answer that batches the transactions that should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, I was looking into that now as well, but not sure how to batch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you have around 25 million relationships to process, performing all of that in a single transaction is not going to work. Write operations of this magnitude need to be batched so as not to blow your heap or hang Neo4j.

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) is your best bet here, it has support for taking an input query and [executing operations upon that input in batches](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate).

Here's how you might use this for your query:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"match (:Node1)-[c:Relation]->(:Node2)
 return c", 
"SET c.attribute = false", 
{iterateList:true, parallel:false}) YIELD batches, errorMessages
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thank you very much, currently getting the APOC plugin, but I think this should be it!

Comment: 25 million rel updates will still take some time. You may need to let it chew on it for awhile, but due the batching you shouldn't see memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf` and uncomment the line `dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687`. After, restart Neo4j.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, this did not help. I tried that before. Also in my config file I do not have that line, the only thing I have is this:

    # Bolt connector
    dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
    #dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
    dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

I am assuming dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687 is what you meant right?

Comment: Hi @SirTobi According to [this post](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/) in the knowledge base you should uncomment the line `dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687`. If the line does not exist I think you can create it.

Comment: Hi Bruno Peres, Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately this also did not solve the issue. the weird thing is, that every other query I am running works just as expected, so the connection should be alright. Super strange... The query runs for a while then stops and throws the above-mentioned error. The query is also not that complicated (see above)